# Node.js and Socket.io: on ssl protocol switching is pending forever

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

When I want to connect to a node server through client, protocol switching is pending forever. Can someone tell me why that's happening?

Here is the server-side code:

```
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');

var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('*******'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('*******'),
    passphrase: '*******',
    rejectUnauthorized: false
};

var app = https.createServer(options);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);
app.listen(3700);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (client) {

    client.on('join', function() {

        //
    });
});
```

And here's the client-side one:

```
var baseURL          = getBaseURL();
var socketIOPort     = 3700;
var socketIOLocation = baseURL + socketIOPort;
var socket           = io.connect(socketIOLocation, {secure: true,   rejectUnauthorized: false});

function getBaseURL()
{
    return (location.protocol + "//" + location.hostname + ":" + location.port);
}
```

I'm using self-signed certificates on localhost.

Mozilla says the connection is aborted and tries to reconnect, Chrome is saying the status is '101 Switching protocols' and time(latency) is 'Pending'.

Answer (score 1):

`getBaseURL()` already includes a port (`location.port`) but then you append to that `3700`. Remove the `location.port` from `getBaseURL()` and that should fix that particular problem.

Comment: mscdex, it didn't help, unfortunately. It still shows that message =(

Comment: Also, is your client html and javascript served over https?

Comment: A third thing, did you try to add the certificate to your browser's exclusion list or add the self-signed CA to your browser/OS's list of trusted CAs?

Comment: socketIOLocation is https://localhost:3700. And yes ALL content is served through https. Browser has already asked me to confirm security exception and I already added the self-signed CA to the list of trusted ones.

Comment: mscdex, I finally found what was the problem. The websocket client script file was in the wrong template file in my laravel project. That was causing the problem establishing the connection to the server. Anyway, thanks for your effort mscdex, your answer helped me to solve the problem overall. I've voted up your answer.